# I am using Angular Universal for server side rendering, but i am not getting the images rendered from server side

Tags: angular, angular-universal

It works fine with client rendering.I can see angular prod build contains assets folder, but Node server build doesn't have any assets with it? Node server is working and able to render the Index page, but images are not rendered. More over my images are taken using routes as localhost:4000/src/assets/image.jpg, which in network tab gives me status 304.
Please find my code below:

```
angular.json***********


 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "study-analytics-webclient": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "study-analytics-webclient:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "study-analytics-webclient:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "study-analytics-webclient:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }

},
"study-analytics-webclient-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e/",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "study-analytics-webclient:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "study-analytics-webclient:serve:production"
        }
      }
    },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "study-analytics-webclient"
}








Webpack.server.config.js*************


const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    server: './server.ts',
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}`


server.ts************

    import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');
// const {  AppServerModuleNgFactory } = (module as any).exports;
const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');



app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

//my functions
// app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
//   res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
// });

// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.render('index', { req });
// });

// app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));


//ends

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


tsconfig.server.js***********

    {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // Set the module format to "commonjs":
    "module": "commonjs",

    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code so that we can help you?

Comment: Can you help now? @AdityaGupta , you have got all the code you needed! Thankyou in advance!

Comment: I wish I could. Not familiar with angular. I would recommend editing your code snippets into groups instead of everything inside one code block. This formats the code into a more readable format and thus attracts relevant users to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing pre-rendering and express rendering code. You need to replace:

```
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});
```

with

```
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
```